# Http_referrer and content-type in WEB API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

There is an issue that when I call an API with POST and

```
content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

then `Request.Headers["Referer"]` is null but with `content-type=application/json` is not null?

How is this possible?

Comment: The `Referer` header allows a server to identify a page where people are visiting it from. And per my test with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json` they both send request without header `Referer`. Could you pls share more details about how you send the request?

Comment: How do you call the api in both cases?